# XNA game - Play a Video as Starting Screen

Tags: c#, xna, screen

I want to play a video as my XNA game start Screen. The game is a 3D game (**XNA 3.1**) (**Based on the famous XNA Racing Game - http://exdream.com/XnaRacingGame/**). I use **IGameScreen** Interface. I want to play a video (***wmv*** format file) with the **game starting**. It is not necessary to play the video in full screen.

Please, help me out.
Thank you.

Comment: Surely if you've been able to develop an entire game to completion, displaying a video should be a trivial task?

Comment: dmttk, could you post the code of what your IGameScreen interface looks like?

Answer (score 3):

Make a new IGameScreen that is added to your Game on startup.  Have it forward to a different IGameScreen when the user either hits a key or after X seconds where X is the length of your game.

As members of your GameScreen object, you will want a [VideoPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.videoplayer.aspx) and Video member.  Like so...

```
VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
Video video;
```

In your GameScreen LoadContent you will need to load your video and if you haven't yet done so create your VideoPlayer object.  Like so...

```
video = content.Load<Video>("yourvideoname");
videoPlayer = new VideoPlayer();
```

Ok, now at some point you will want to start your video player.  You could do this in your Update method the first time you're in there.  Don't do it on every call of the Update.

```
videoPlayer.Play(video)
```

Everytime your Draw method gets called you want to get the texture from the video player of the latest frame, but only if the video player is playing.  If the texture is populated, draw it.  You must specify the destination rectangle you want it to be at or you can choose one of the other SpriteBatch.Draw overloads.  Make sure that you have called the SpriteBatch.Begin/End calls in your code.

```
if(videoPlayer.State != MediaState.Stopped)
{
  Texture2D texture = videoPlayer.GetTexture();
  if(texture != null)
  {
    spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Rectangle(0, 0, YOURWIDTH, YOURHEIGHT),
        Color.White);
  }
}
```

There's definately some improvements you could do code-wise to help out the garbage collector and make this more performant (like don't create a new Rectangle everytime), but this is the low-down of showing a video.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer. But I already tried this way. But it didn't work with the IGameScreen Interface. In my IGameScreen Interface has one method called "Render". So I can not use the normal override methods (like LoadContent, Draw,....). When I used those methods, there was a error ("no suitable method found to override"). Because I used IGameScreen Interface in my Video playing class.Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: @Hexxagonal isn't Rectangle a value type? If so it wont have any performance impact on the GC. Not sure though - I'd be very surprised if it was a reference type..

Comment: It is. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.aspx As you see, "struct".

Comment: Hmm... never realized that. Thanks Scott/Matt.